# How to install build tools in Android Studio

Tags: android

it shows to install build tools revision 26.0.2 but the first time it showed I clicked and downloaded it  but it was cancelled due to my network error and the second time when I clicked ,it is not downloading

can anybody tell me how to download it ??

[image]

Comment: close project and open again then try it

Comment: Click "Instal Build Tools 26.0.2 and sync project"

Comment: I tried it but not working

Comment: Project Clean and Build try it..

Comment: You would probably want to look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html

Answer (score 0):

Restart Android Studio and the message should be shown again. You can also do it from Android SDK. Go to tools-> Android-> SDK Manager. There you can install everything you need. If you need more details about what is already installed, check show details checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Update your android gradle plugin to `3.0.1`. In your project level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Go to your module level `build.gradle` file and remove the line that says

`buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'`

It will automatically use a minimum default.